# The flow failed to access the value for $Record.XXX for grandchild field of dependent picklist structure when referenced in Text Template

Tags: visual-workflow

**Given Case object with a three level dependent picklist structure:**

- `Case.Reason__c` (picklist)
- `Case.Reason_Detail__c` (dependent picklist controlled by `Case.Reason__c`)
- `Case.Reason_Subdetail__c` (dependent picklist controlled by `Case.Reason_Detail__c`)

**Given a record-triggered flow**

- That executes upon *deletion* of the Case and uses the Send Email action

**Given a text template used in the Send Email action that references each of the three aforementioned Case fields**

```
Case Reason: {!$Record.Reason__c}
Case Reason Detail: {!$Record.Reason_Detail__c}
Case Reason Subdetail: {!$Record.Reason_SubDetail__c}
```

**When a Case is deleted**

- where all three levels of the picklist hierarchy are NULL

**Then, the Flow aborts with ...**

```
Error element Alert_stakeholders (FlowActionCall).
The flow failed to access the value for $Record.Reason_SubDetail__c because it hasn't been set or assigned.
```

---

*I don't get this*. The `$Record` flow variable has access to all of the fields in the deleted case. And, if the `Case.Reason_Subdetail__c` has a value, the flow works fine and renders the email as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I can't explain why this fails but I can provide a workaround:

- Introduce a formula element `CaseReasonSubdetail` that wraps the `Case.Reason_Subdetail__c` as follows:

  ```
  BLANKVALUE(TEXT({!$Record.Reason_Subdetail__c}),NULL)
  ```
- And change the text template to reference the formula

  ```
  Case Reason: {!$Record.Reason__c}
  Case Reason Detail: {!$Record.Reason_Detail__c}
  Case Reason Subdetail: {!CaseReasonSubDetail}  <<-- the formula field
  ```

*Note that this error occurs only for the third level of the dependent picklist - which I realize makes no sense. The formula field workaround was not required for level one or two - even when the values for those fields were NULL.*